# Is it possible to execute REPAST model immediately from the IDE

Tags: agent-based-modeling, repast-simphony

Is it possible to run my simulation directly without seeing the GUI? All I am interested in are console output data, so there is no need for me to interact with a GUI to play, pause or reset my simulation.

Comment: Related question: https://github.com/Repast/repast.simphony/issues/18

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. The easiest way to do this is to run it as a batch model (even if you only run one run at a time).

If you're using the standard distribution with Eclipse and have created projects as described in the docs, you will have a `Run configuration` called `Batch <your_model_name> model` If you run this, you'll launch in batch mode - input parameters will be taken from a batch file you write as a one off job (or as often as you want to change parameters).

[See this documentation](http://repast.sourceforge.net/docs/RepastBatchRunsGettingStarted.pdf) for more information on how to set up and run batch models.

Comment: Here is a command line command that worked for me D:/EclipseJava/app/jdk/bin/java.exe -cp "./lib/*;./bin/." repast.simphony.batch.BatchMain -params ./batch/batch_params.xml  -interactive ./MyModelSettings.rs